# Can not display the image using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I can not display the image using `ng-file-upload` using angular.js. I am uploading the multiple images. My code is given below.

```
<div ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Image{{$index+1}}:</span>
<div>
 <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}"  ng-model="mul.image"  ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<span class="input-group-btn" ng-show="mulImage.length>0">
<img ngf-thumbnail="mul.image" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.image !=null">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" ng-click="addNewImageRow(mulImage);" ng-show="$last"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"  ng-show="mulImage.length>1" ng-click="deleteNewImageRow(mulImage,$index);" ngf-select="onFileSelect1($index);">
 </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
 $scope.mulImage=[];
         $scope.mulImage.push({'image':null});
         $scope.buttonName="Submit";
         $scope.addNewImageRow=function(mulImage){
       mulImage.push({'image':null});

       }
       $scope.deleteNewImageRow=function(mulImage,index){
           mulImage.splice(index,1);
       }

       $scope.onFileSelect1 = function(index) {
       }
```

Here I am unable to display the image after selecting from folder in `ngf-thumbnail`.

Comment: surely you can provide a more detailed problem description than *"unable to display image"* which is virtually meaningless and provides no troubleshooting feedback whatsoever

Comment: can you debug the image string value?

Comment: its not coming at all.i have also included `ngFileUpload`. After selecting from drive it should display there but not happening like that.

Comment: maybe you missed $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 0):

try adding $scope.$apply();

```
$scope.addNewImageRow=function(mulImage){
    mulImage.push({'image':null});
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: I added there but still same issue.

Comment: but did the value of image string change. Can you display it's value and observe if it's change

Comment: also your image value is null?

Comment: when selecting it should add in ng-model. I implented it before but here its not working.

Comment: So your problem is not displaying the image it is that ng-model doesn't work, right?